# Citing full named organizations in references but using abbreviation in-text only

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to cite some  stuff from websites from geological studying organizations. I wanted to display the shortened name in my text, but letting both the abbreviation and full name in "references" like this. I use texstudio with bibtex.
Let's just say the organization is FBI and I talking about an online page. 
I.e:

- Text:

  ```
  According to the portraits of clowns \cite{fbi} they are very scary(...)
  ```
- References:

  ```
  @misc{FBI
  author={FBI - Federal Bureau of Investigation},
  title={Report of something evil},
  url= {https://www.fbi.com/FakeClownsAsExample},
  year={2018},
  note={accessed  APRIL 30}
  }
  ```

My issues are the following:
**url**: url never showed the link address in references. I've tried several things but only "howpublished" worked. I'm using it ever since. It's not a big of a deal.

**author**: I want the reference to have both initials and full name:  "FBI -Federal Bureau of Investigation" as author. However the author,in the text, appears as "of Investigation". It shows up as "FBI-Federal Bureau of Investigation" if I use double "{}" in mybib over author, but so it does in my text (I want it to appear as "FBI" only there).

Any idea on how to that ?

edit: *TL,DR: FBI must be shown was FBI when I refer to it  in my text and must be shown as "FBI- Federal Bureau Investigation (or similar)" in the reference page.*

Comment: People will need to know what bibliography system you are using: bibtex? biblatex? natbib? with what style?

Comment: I'm using bibtex with texstudio. 
I'm not sure whether  my question was clear enough or not because english is not my first language. If anything is confusing please let me know !

Comment: Best at least tell us what bibtex style you use. Ideal would be a minimal working example. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Comment: Your code stopped working because of the bullets -- it needed more indentation. Fixed.